# Traefik K8s CORS error: CORS request did not succeed

Tags: kubernetes, cors, traefik-ingress

I have a `web` and `api` microservice. Both need to be exposed to external traffic. Traefik is my ingress controller and it was installed using the helm chart where version = 23.2.0

I am using Traefik for TLS termination. I am also using a middleware to redirect the `web's` service http to https. The web service is available at `web.all.com` and the `api` is available at `api.all.com`

The `web` pod also has information about the `api` url, where the logic is such that it calls the `api` url `https://api.all.com` .

Below is my Ingress related manifests.

Web ingress:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: redirect-to-https
  namespace: dev
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    permanent: true
    scheme: https
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: web-redirect
  namespace: dev
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`web.all.com`)
    middlewares:
    - name: redirect-to-https
    services:
    - name: web
      namespace: dev
      port: 80
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: web-tls
  namespace: dev
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`web.all.com`)
    services:
    - name: web
      namespace: dev
      port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: web-dev-secret
```

Api Ingress:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: dev
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`api.all.com`)
    services:
    - name: api
      namespace: dev
      port: 8000
  tls:
    secretName: dev-api-secret
```

When I try to open web.all.com on Firefox and inspect the page, I get the below error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.all.com (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

What do I need to do in traefik ingress files to fix this? I don't think people will be willing to add cors plugins in their browser.

Comment: Did you try to access your API and web without ingress by using a direct load balancer or node port service? I faced the same issue and the reason was web app wasn't able to get data from API. It has nothing to do with CORS in my case.

Comment: Yeah it works without ingress and with NodePorts. If I setup the web and api as http minus the TLS terminate etc...it works..